# Using 'or' twice in a sentence

Tags: grammar, conjunctions

Can I use 'or' twice in this sentence?

> I don’t know whether it was a last-minute programme or they didn’t get information about the programme or the school did not get to inform the parents on time.

Or should I write

> I don’t know whether it was a last-minute programme, they didn’t get information about the programme or the school did not get to inform the parents on time.

Comment: My personal preference would be to use a comma to avoid making it a runon sentence; I'd also add a comma before the or just to make the three possibilities more distinct.

Comment: I have rephrased the sentence to 

I don’t know whether it was because it was a last-minute programme, they didn’t get information about the programme, or the school did not get to inform the parents on time.

It seems better now. Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the first.  Many people prefer the second, but there is no "law" requiring the second style.

Comment: Based on readings on the Internet, I guess it's true @Hot Licks. It looks like the first one is common in speaking form but not in writing. Thank you.

Comment: The comma-separated list is just an abbreviated form of the and/or separated list.  Conceptually you start with and/or separation and substitute commas according to one of the "rules" (there are several versions).  Using and/or (as appropriate) instead of commas in a list is never "wrong", just sometimes "not idiomatic".

Answer (score 0):

Using *whether* usually implies exactly two options, except when *whether* is used to mark the options.

Personally, I would use comma, but use *whether* in each instance to mark where it begins and ends:

> I don’t know whether it was a last-minute programme, whether they didn’t get information about the programme, or whether the school did not get to inform the parents on time.